# Where are the details about Directed Graph Markup Language (DGML)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dgml

[Skinner's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/camerons/archive/tags/DGML/default.aspx) has some nice introductory material for the new Directed Graph Markup Language in Visual Studio 2010, but I'd like more. Anyone know where to find some details documents or specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the VS 2010 RC documentation for DGML documents here: [Exploring Existing Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409365%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842619.aspx) is a nice guide to how the markup works.